# Sever code spawing too many instances of php

Tags: php, cron, silverstripe

I've got a sever which has an action triggered by a frequent cron job.
This is a php application build on Silverstripe (4.0).
The issue I'm facing is the php processes stay alive and also keep database connections open. This means after a few days the site stops working entirely once SQL stops accepting new connections.

The system has two tasks on cron jobs;

One takes a massive CSV file and spits it into smaller sub files which are then imported into the database. This one uses a lock file to prevent it running into a previously running instance. I'm not too sure if this is working.

The second task processes all the records which have been updated in large batches.

Either of these could be the source of the overloading but I'm not sure how to narrow it down.
What's the best way to diagnose the source of the issue?

Comment: Typically what sort of range of number of records are being inserted into the db from the CSV file? Are the updates coming from the same CSV file? How often does the CSV file get updated?

Comment: The source CSV files can be as large as 750k records, but do not often get updated. The batch sizes I've been experimenting with is 500 and 1000

Comment: Can whatever is generating the CSV files be set to generate smaller CSV files? How often are the inserts and updates required to be done?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of debugging, this would be like any other task profiling the application with something like [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) and [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).  To ensure that processes do not run for too long you can limit the [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) for the `PHP.ini` for the `CLI`.

To then let the `CLI` process run for a long time, but only just enough time add something to set the max execution time on a per row basis:

```
$allowed_seconds_per_row = 3;
foreach($rows_to_process as $row){
    set_time_limit($allowed_seconds_per_row);
    $this->process($row);
}
```

You can also [register a shutdown function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to record the state as the script ends.

It is likely that the memory is a key cause for failure and debugging focused on the [memory usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) and that can be controlled by [unsetting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) variable data as needed.